# Prime numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays, primes

I need to write a function that recieve from the user a number(n), and the function return an array with all the prime numbers until the user number(n).
I know how to write the function that check if number is prime, but i dont know how to enter the numbers to an array.. for example if the user entered 53, it will return [2 ,3 ,5 ,7 ,11 ,13 ,17 ,19 ,23 ,29 ,31 ,37 ,41 ,43 ,47 ,53].
I forgot to tell that the language is java.. my bad!

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Use List (List<int> in C#, ArrayList<int> in Java etc) and finally convert it into array

Comment: "How to enter the numbers to an array"? Well, that depends on the language you want to use which you did not tell us! Looks like you should start reading some documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code

```
private ArrayList getPrimeNumbers(int number)
{
    ArrayList primeNumbers = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i)) 
        {
            primeNumbers.add(i);
        }
    }
    return primeNumbers;
} 


private boolean isPrime(int n) 
{
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) 
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you do it without the ArrayList?

Comment: There is no specific length of the prime number list, so you can create new Array of length same as ArrayList and then return that array.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you *can't* change *array length*, so you should use the appropriate 
collection where you can add items; that is `List<>` in C#, `ArrayList<>` in Java etc.

Technically, you can implement separate `IsPrime` method and then check the integers in `2..max` range, but here it can just be inlined.

Possible code in C#

```
public static int[] GetPrimes(int max) {
  if (max <= 1)
    return new int[0];
  else if (max == 2) // <- let's process the only even prime (2) separately
    return new int[] { 2 };

  List<int> primes = new List<int>() { 2, 3 };

  // Sieve through odd numbers:    
  for (int i = 5; i <= max; i += 2) {
    int sqrt = (int) Math.Sqrt(i + 1);

    Boolean isPrime = true;

    // There's no need to check if (i % primes[0] == 0):
    // primes[0] == 2, and loop is for odd numbers - 5, 7, 9,...
    for (int j = 1; primes[j] <= sqrt; ++j)
      if ((i % primes[j]) == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }

    if (isPrime)
      primes.Add(i);
  }

  return primes.ToArray();
}
// ....
// Test will return the string
// "2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53"
String result = String.Join(", ", GetPrimes(53).Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Comment: @Will Ness: Sorry, I've run GetPrime(2) with [2] output; GetPrime(3) and GetPrime(3) with [2, 3] output and GetPrime(5) with [2, 3, 5] output. It seems that it's alright. However I've made correction in my optimization - "3" now appears once as it should be

Comment: Yes, I'm testing all the odds, but I'm doing it efficiently (sieve):
I'm trying prime dividers only, e.g. for 121 I'll try 3, 5, 7, 11 but 
not 9.

Comment: @Will Ness: Thank you! You're quite right: I can well start the inner loop from 1, not from 0.

Comment: I've changed your sentence about sieve. This is not a sieve in any way. You in fact test here all the (odd) numbers below max, with an inlined `IsPrime` code (as trial division algorithm). But overall, +1 for at least having an *optimal* trial division here, unlike the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (you did not specify language, so I'm using Python):

```
def GetPrimes(n):
    array = []
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if IsPrime(i):
            array.append(i)
    return array

def IsPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,n/2+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

print GetPrimes(53)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code will work, Give it a try
package CoreJava;
public class prime {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int a [] ={1, 2, 3, 7, 23,7,10};
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
    {
    if((a[i]!=0) &&(a[i]!=1))
    {
    for(int j=2;j<a[i];j++)
    {
      if(a[i]%j==0)
    {
       flag=1;
       break;
    }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
     System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    }
    
    }
}
```

}